# UpdatePanel not refreshing

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

I'm a newbie with ASP.NET, so probably my question is easy... but I'm wasting a lot of time with no success.
Part of my page is

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="pnlFileUpload" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <ajaxToolkit:AsyncFileUpload ID="upload" runat="server" OnUploadedComplete="upload_UploadedComplete"
            OnUploadedFileError="upload_UploadedFileError" UploaderStyle="Modern" UploadingBackColor="Yellow"
            Width="400px" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="pnlFileError" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblFileError" runat="server" Text="errFile" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="upload" EventName="UploadedComplete" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

When user uploads (started with `ajaxToolkit:AsyncFileUpload`) ends, `upload_UploadedComplete` is called.
A sample code is:

```
protected void upload_UploadedComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
{
    int size = upload.PostedFile.ContentLength;
    if (size > maxsize)
    {
        lblFileError.Text = 'File too big...';
        lblFileError.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        lblFileError.Visible = true;
        pnlFileError.Update();
    }
}
```

But `lblFileError` is never shown... why?!?

Answer (score 0):

AsyncFileupload doesn't need updatePanel ( none of AJAx toolkit controls need ) . as they have it as a built in . remove fileupload UpdatePanel and test again

:

it seems you can't do that in this way . based on AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite to show user a message about uploading file you should use "ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock" as below :

```
protected void upload_UploadedComplete(object sender,  AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
{
   int size = upload.PostedFile.ContentLength;
   if (size > maxsize)
    {
      ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "error", "top.$get(\"" + lblFileError.ClientID + "\").innerHTML = 'File too big...';", true);

    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work, as I supposed. `AsyncFileUpload` works very well: problem is that, after upload, `lblFileError` is never shown even if inside an `UpdatePanel` manually updated...

Comment: thanks for your post, I'll try as soon as I can. Anyway this solution doesn't solve my probem: what if I need to show another panel to let user do something else? I know there must be a solution...